# My first OOP aproach in Codeigniter

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to make a crawler to fetch templates from sites that don't offer any API access for later display as affiliate.
I just started with CI, read the documentation a few times and below you can find my first OOP approach.
My question is if I'm on the right path of OOP or if are (I'm sure there are) any improvements available to my code. I read alot of OOP tutorials on the web and people seems to have different views of the OOP coding.

Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
class Crawler extends CI_Model {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_with_curl($url) {
    if(!ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
        return $this->html = file_get_html($url);
    } else {
        $curl = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        $str = curl_exec($curl);  
        curl_close($curl);  

        return $this->html = str_get_html($str);
    }
}

function array_arrange($links){
    $links = array_merge(array_unique($links));
    foreach (range(1, count($links), 2) as $k) {
        unset($links[$k]);
    }
    return array_merge($links);
}

function diff($source,$links){
    $this->db->like('source', $source);
    $this->db->from('themes');
    $total = $this->db->count_all_results();

    if($total >= count($links)){
        return false;
    } else {
        $diff = count($links)-$total;
        $data = array_slice($links,-$diff,$diff,true);
        return $data;
    }
}

function get_links($url,$find){
    $this->html = $this->get_with_curl($url);
    foreach($this->html->find($find) as $v){
        $data[] = $v->href;
    }
    $this->html->clear();
    unset($this->html);

    return $data;
}

function themefyme(){
    $links = $this->get_links('http://themify.me/themes','ul[class=theme-list] li a');
    $links = $this->array_arrange($links);
    $links = $this->diff('themefyme',$links);
    if($links){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($links as $link){
            $this->html = $this->get_with_curl($link);
            $data[$i]['source']         = 'themefyme';
            $data[$i]['name']           = strtok($this->html->find('h1', 0)->plaintext,' ');
            $data[$i]['link']           = $link;
            $data[$i]['demo']           = 'http://themify.me/demo/#theme='.strtolower($data[$i]['name']);
            $data[$i]['price']          = filter_var($this->html->find('h1 sup', 0)->plaintext, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $data[$i]['description']    = $this->html->find('big', 0)->plaintext;
            $data[$i]['features']       = $this->html->find('ul', 0)->plaintext;
            $data[$i]['img_large']      = $this->html->find('.theme-large-screen img', 0)->src;
            $data[$i]['img_thumb']      = 'http://themify.me/wp-content/themes/themify/thumb.php?src='.$data[$i]['img_large'].'&q=90&w=220';
            $i++;

            $this->html->clear();
            unset($this->html);
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('themes', $data); 
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}

function themefuse(){
    $links = $this->get_links('http://www.themefuse.com/wp-themes-shop/','.theme-img a');
    $links = $this->array_arrange($links);
    $links = $this->diff('themefuse',$links);
    if($links){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($links as $link){
            $this->html = $this->get_with_curl($link);
            $data[$i]['source']         = 'themefuse';
            $data[$i]['name']           = $this->html->find('.theme-price', 0)->plaintext;
            $data[$i]['link']           = $link;
            $data[$i]['demo']           = 'http://themefuse.com/demo/wp/'.strtolower($data[$i]['name']).'/';
            $data[$i]['description']    = $this->html->find('.short-descr', 0)->plaintext;
            $data[$i]['highlights']     = $this->html->find('.highlights', 0)->outertext;
            $data[$i]['features']       = $this->html->find('.col-features', 0)->outertext;
            $data[$i]['theme_info']     = $this->html->find('.col-themeinfo', 0)->outertext;
                                          preg_match("/src=(.*?)&amp;/",$this->html->find('.slideshow img', 0)->src, $img);
            $data[$i]['img_large']      = $img[1];
            $data[$i]['img_thumb']      = 'http://themefuse.com/wp-content/themes/themefuse/thumb.php?src='.$img[1].'&h=225&w=431&zc=1&q=100';
            $i++;

            $this->html->clear();
            unset($this->html);
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('themes', $data); 
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: This is not OOP. These are functions wrapped in a class.

Comment: Also, you'd most probably be better off without codeigniter as it is unprofessional and would most likely result in bad code quality. Zend or Symfony2 would be a far better idea. To answer your question, you'll need to look up tons of things like *separation of concerns*, *dependency injection* along with using *interfaces*, *design patterns*, *single responsibility principle* and so on... You might wonder how would it pay off? Well, high quality OO code pays off very well through readability, reusability, maintainability and extensibility. It worth the time, believe me.

Comment: Is there an exact solution to your question? It seems a bit vague...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PeeHaa says, your example isn't really OOP. OOP means Object Oriented Programming, which basically means that your classes (objects) should represent an entity as if it was a physical object. So your class would be a group of functions (methods) that relate to the object.

For example, a `Robot` Object, might have functions like, moveForward, moveBackword, speak etc.

And you might have another Robot type that can do all of the things that the `Robot` object can do, but in a slightly different way. For example, your might have a `MoonRobot` object that `extends` the `Robot` object (which would inherit all of `Robot`s functions) but it's `moveForward` function might be different, so this can be altered in the `MoonRobot` class.

Comment: Rather `MoonRobot implements Robot` :) You *substitute* method implementations after all. But your explanation is right.

Comment: @Powerslave good point! You could use a Robot interface, however if you had a Robot MK1 and you extended your Robot with a segway, his moveForward function would be to lean forward instead of move his legs :) Just kidding

Comment: to extend (or "implements") @MajorCaiger's solid example, you could build a "Crawler" class with generic functions that are "actions any ThemeCrawler can do", including a getTheme() function. Then you could build a second class called FymeCrawler that "implements (think "inherits from") Crawler. in FymeCrawler you wold override the getTheme() function with the code in your current ThemeFyme function. Then you could create a 3rd class that also "implements" Crawler called ThemeFuse whose getTheme() function also overrides Crawler::getTheme() with code specific to the Fuse Themes

Comment: @MajorCaiger hahaha! I like segways btw

Comment: It doesn't have to be physical object, abstract concepts are just as ok too and in fact far more common probably.